# Inverted Mouse on Secondary monitor

Tags: display, mouse-cursor

After rotating my Primary monitor 90 degrees (Portrait), the mouse is inverted on the (landscape) secondary monitor, how can I fix this?  Even my tech cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of graphics card do you have?

You need to go into the control panel applet for your graphics and specify the rotation of your monitor.